# Why does my apache server still execute my cgi script after I changed User directive from daemon to apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

For security, I created an apache user without shell and home directory in my system. Then I changed User directive from daemon to apache in `httpd.conf`. It creates sub processes in apache to run as apache user.

Why does my apache server still execute my cgi shell script with apache user without shell?

Answer (score 1):

Your apache user does not have a login shell or home directory. That is good.

However, "not having a shel" does not mean that the user cannot run shell scripts. That is something different entirely.

You have configured the httpd daemon to run as user "apache", so all processes it starts will also run as user "apache", including CGI cripts. And this is as intended.

Comment: Thank you Krist van Besien. Now I am confusing "not having a shell does not mean that the user cannot run shell scripts". I do not find myself the way to examine it on my system. Could you please make it clear ?

Comment: What I mean is that "not having a shell" does not have the meaning you  seem to attach to it. When we say that a user doesn't have a shell this means that the user does not have a "login shell", ie that the user cannot log in to an interactive shell session. However a process running under such a user id can still start other processes. A CGI script can be a shell script (but id doesn't have to be) and in such a case apache will start a non interactive shell to run the script in.

Comment: Thank you again! I got it. I did an experiment to examine it. I sure apache user does not have any login shells. When I execute CGI, I find what process running the CGI. It is apache user. As you said, apache server cannot log in to an interactive shell but it is possible to start a non interactive shell follow shebang line declared in CGI script. Bash or sh shell both allow other to read and execute (0755)  so apache user is able to do it.